# Как скачать все картинки с сайта с#?

Tags: c#

Привет! Подскажите, как можно скачать все картинки с сайта? Я понимаю, как сделать так, что бы можно было скачать одну картинку.Нашел код на этом сайте  и здесь все понятно.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri("");
        client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, "picture.jpg" );
        Console.WriteLine("Картинка скачана");
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

А как сделать, что бы можно было скачать все картинки, например, с сайта инстаграмм. Я думаю, что нужно создать массив и все картинки заносить в него и код выше заключить либо в в foreach, или что-то типо

```
for (int i = 1; i <= pictures; i++) {  
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri(" ");
        client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, "picture.jpg" );
        Console.WriteLine("Картинка скачана");
        Console.Read();
    }
```

Но как определить все картинки на сайте?

Comment: `client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, "picture.jpg" );` без ожидания не очень правильно.

Comment: А что значит все картинки? всё содержимое тегов img? или также содержимое свойства CSS `background-image`?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Только фотографии, например

Comment: @dreenline: Ого, а как вы предлагаете отличать фотографию от просто элемента дизайна?

Comment: @VladD Собственно, в том и вопрос:) Как определить все фотографии на сайте и вообще, возможно ли это. Я новичок, поэтому, возможно, мои вопросы могут показаться довольно глупыми

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В вопросе не указано какого-либо конкретного сайта, поэтому отвечу и предложу технику, которая подойдёт для любого сайта.

---

В задаче используется решение только для картинок атрибуте `src` тэга `img`, но решение на данной основе также возможно и для картинок в `background-image`. Оно сложнее, но также возможно. Для Javascript обращений для простоты используется jQuery, предполагая, что на целевом сайте он тоже есть. Но это может быть также чистый JavaScript либо другая библиотека при условии, что эта библиотека используется на сайте.

---

Используйте библиотеку [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) для решения подобных задач.

### Что это такое?

Это управляемая оболочка над CEF ([Chromium Embedded Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework)). То есть Вы получаете мощь Chromium, которой управляете программно.

### Почему именно CEF/CefSharp?

- Не стоит заморачиваться парсингом страниц (а это сложная и неблагодарная задача, которую крайне не рекомендую делать).
- Можно работать с уже загруженной страницей (после выполнения скриптов).
- Есть возможность выполнять произвольный JavaScript с последними возможностями.
- Даёт возможность вызывать AJAX с помощью JavaScript, а затем при успехе (success), дёргать события в C#-коде с результатом AJAX.

### Разновидности CeSharp

- CefSharp.WinForms
- CefSharp.Wpf
- CefSharp.OffScreen

Первые две используются если вам надо дать пользователям элемент управления "Браузер". Концептуально похоже на [WebBrowser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) в Windows Forms, который является оболочкой для управления IE, а не Chromium, как в нашем случае.

Поэтому мы будем использовать CefSharp.OffScreen (закадровую) разновидность.

### Написание кода

Допустим у нас консольное приложение, но это уже зависит от Вас.

Устанавливаем Nuget-пакет CefSharp.OffScreen 51-ой версии:

```
Install-Package CefSharp.OffScreen -Version 51.0.0
```

Дело в том, что C# всё массивы маппает к `List<object>`, результат JavaScript обёрнут в `object`, в котором уже содержатся `List<object>`, `string`, `bool`, `int` в зависимости от результата. Для того чтобы сделать результаты строго типизированными, создаём небольшой ConvertHelper:

```
public static class ConvertHelper
{
    public static T[] GetArrayFromObjectList<T>(object obj)
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<object>)obj)
            .Cast<T>()
            .ToArray();
    }

    public static List<T> GetListFromObjectList<T>(object obj)
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<object>)obj)
            .Cast<T>()
            .ToList();
    }

    public static T ToTypedVariable<T>(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            dynamic dynamicResult = null;
            return dynamicResult;
        }

        Type type = typeof(T);
        if (type.IsArray)
        {
            dynamic dynamicResult = typeof(ConvertHelper).GetMethod(nameof(GetArrayFromObjectList))
                .MakeGenericMethod(type.GetElementType())
                .Invoke(null, new[] { obj });
            return dynamicResult;
        }

        if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
        {
            dynamic dynamicResult = typeof(ConvertHelper).GetMethod(nameof(GetListFromObjectList))
                .MakeGenericMethod(type.GetGenericArguments().Single())
                .Invoke(null, new[] { obj });
            return dynamicResult;
        }

        return (T)obj;
    }
}
```

Создаём класс CefSharpWrapper:

```
public sealed class CefSharpWrapper
{
    private ChromiumWebBrowser _browser;

    public void InitializeBrowser()
    {
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();

        // Disable GPU in WPF and Offscreen until GPU issues has been resolved
        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-gpu", "1");

        //Perform dependency check to make sure all relevant resources are in our output directory.
        Cef.Initialize(settings, shutdownOnProcessExit: true, performDependencyCheck: true);

        _browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();

        // wait till browser initialised
        AutoResetEvent waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        EventHandler onBrowserInitialized = null;

        onBrowserInitialized = (sender, e) =>
        {
            _browser.BrowserInitialized -= onBrowserInitialized;

            waitHandle.Set();
        };

        _browser.BrowserInitialized += onBrowserInitialized;

        waitHandle.WaitOne();
    }

    public void ShutdownBrowser()
    {
        // Clean up Chromium objects.  You need to call this in your application otherwise
        // you will get a crash when closing.
        Cef.Shutdown();
    }

    public Task<T> GetResultAfterPageLoad<T>(string pageUrl, Func<Task<T>> onLoadCallback)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<T> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();

        EventHandler<LoadingStateChangedEventArgs> onPageLoaded = null;

        T t = default(T);

        // An event that is fired when the first page is finished loading.
        // This returns to us from another thread.
        onPageLoaded = async (sender, e) =>
        {
            // Check to see if loading is complete - this event is called twice, one when loading starts
            // second time when it's finished
            // (rather than an iframe within the main frame).
            if (!e.IsLoading)
            {
                // Remove the load event handler, because we only want one snapshot of the initial page.
                _browser.LoadingStateChanged -= onPageLoaded;

                t = await onLoadCallback();

                tcs.SetResult(t);
            }
        };

        _browser.LoadingStateChanged += onPageLoaded;

        _browser.Load(pageUrl);

        return tcs.Task;
    }

    public async Task<T> EvaluateJavascript<T>(string script)
    {
        JavascriptResponse javascriptResponse = await _browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script);

        if (javascriptResponse.Success)
        {
            object scriptResult = javascriptResponse.Result;
            return ConvertHelper.ToTypedVariable<T>(scriptResult);
        }

        throw new ScriptException(javascriptResponse.Message);
    }
}
```

Далее вызываем наш класс `CefSharpWrapper` из метода Main.

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        MainAsync().Wait();
    }

    private static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        CefSharpWrapper wrapper = new CefSharpWrapper();

        wrapper.InitializeBrowser();

        string[] imageUrls = await wrapper.GetResultAfterPageLoad("https://yandex.ru", async () =>
            await wrapper.EvaluateJavascript<string[]>("$('img').map((index, element) => $(element).prop('src')).toArray()"));

        string imageFolder = "C://Test";

        if (!Directory.Exists(imageFolder))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(imageFolder);
        }

        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        for (int i = 0; i < imageUrls.Length; i++)
        {
            string imageUrl = imageUrls[i];
            byte[] fileBytes = await client.DownloadDataTaskAsync(imageUrl);
            // Можете написать алгоритм позволяющий подбирать расширения
            string imagePath = Path.Combine(imageFolder, i + ".jpg");
            File.WriteAllBytes(imagePath, fileBytes);
        }

        wrapper.ShutdownBrowser();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. скачиваешь страницу целевого сайта;
2. парсишь (вся загвоздка в этом, хе-хе) эту страницу в поисках всех ссылок на нужные картинки, сохраняешь все ссылки в список;
3. проходишь в цикле по этому списку и выкачиваешь все нужные картинки.

   P.S. некоторые сайты имеют так называемый API: в ответ на запрос к сайту отдают xml или json формате информацию, с которой гораздо проще работать, чем парсить страницу сайта.

Answer (score 1):

Также напишу свой вариант решения задачи посредством [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp) для парсинга с помощью него HTML\CSS и построения DOM-дерева в C#.

В состав библиотеки входит как и парсер HTML\CSS (BrowsingContext, HtmlParser, CssParser), так и подключаемый JavaScript-движок Jint из пакета AngleSharp.Scripting.JavaScript, с помощью которого можно подключаться к событиям из C# и вызывать код на JavaScript из C# (хотя у меня не получилось вызвать на сайте jQuery код на нем же :), видимо, там ограничения есть).

В данном случае не учитывается необходимость авторизации, т.е. с того же инстаграма не получится все выкачать с помощью моего примера, но с главной pikabu или imgur - вполне

---

Если ограниться получением списка URL из свойства background-image и img.src, то код будет выглядить так:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AngleSharp;
using AngleSharp.Dom.Html;

class WebImageElementParser
{
    private readonly IBrowsingContext _context;

    public WebImageElementParser()
    {
       //AngleSharp BrowsingContext 
        _context = BrowsingContext.New(new Configuration().WithDefaultLoader().WithCss().WithJavaScript());
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetImageUrlsAsync(string siteUrl)
    {
        var documentResult = await _context.OpenAsync(siteUrl);
        //ищем у всех элементов DOM-дерева свойство background-image и берем его значение
        var backgroundImagesUrls = documentResult.QuerySelectorAll("*")
            .Where(htmlElement => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(htmlElement.Style.BackgroundImage))
            .Select(htmlElement => htmlElement.Style.BackgroundImage) //url(\"http://s8.pikabu.ru/video/2016/11/27/7/1480245149289358252.jpg\")
            .Select(styleValue => Regex.Match(styleValue, "\\\"(?<url>.*)\\\"")) //http://s8.pikabu.ru/video/2016/11/27/7/1480245149289358252.jpg 
            .Where(regex => regex.Success)
            .Select(regex => regex.Groups["url"].Value);

        var imgElementUrls = documentResult.Body.QuerySelectorAll("img").Cast<IHtmlImageElement>().Select(img => img.Source);

        return imgElementUrls.Union(backgroundImagesUrls).ToList();
    }
}
```

---

Также написал для примера вариант того, как все полученные изображения скачивать по найденым URL-ам (если в нем, URL, присутствует расширение файла), сохранять их, сгруппировав их по наименованию хоста:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    class WebImageDownloader : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient() { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30) };

        public async Task SaveImageAsync(string imageUrl)
        {
            try {
                Uri imageUri;
                //нам же ведь надо достучаться до ресурса? :)
                if (Uri.TryCreate(imageUrl, UriKind.Absolute, out imageUri)) {
                    using (HttpResponseMessage imageResponse = await _httpClient.GetAsync(imageUri)) {
                        // HTTP result != 200 OK -> HttpRequestException
                        imageResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                        using (Stream imageStream = await imageResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()) {
                            await SaveImageAsync(imageUri, imageStream);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    //обрабатываем неверные url
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Not an absolute URI: {imageUrl}");
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                }
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException e) {
                //обрабатываем ошибки запросов
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.WriteLine($"{e.Message} : {imageUrl}");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            }
        }

        private async Task SaveImageAsync(Uri imageUri, Stream imageStream)
        {
            /*берем Path сегмент (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier)

              и пытаемся вычленить из него последнюю часть ресурса(до слеша) и его расширение

              https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnAAg.jpg?s=32&g=1 -> /pnAAg.jpg (path) -> pnAAg.jpg (regexp)

            */
            Match fileExtensionMatch = Regex.Match(imageUri.AbsolutePath, @"(?!/)[\w\d]+\.\w+", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
            if (fileExtensionMatch.Success) {
                //создаем дерикторию для данного хоста картинки, чтобы хоть как-то их сгруппировать
                string imageDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, $"Images_{imageUri.Host.Replace('.', '_')}");

                if (!Directory.Exists(imageDirectory))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(imageDirectory);

                string fileName = fileExtensionMatch.Value;
                string fullPathForFile = Path.Combine(imageDirectory, fileName);

                using (FileStream newFile = File.Create(fullPathForFile)) {
                    await imageStream.CopyToAsync(newFile);
                    Console.WriteLine($"{imageUri.AbsoluteUri} ----> {fullPathForFile}");
                }
            } else {
                //обрабатываем отсутствие расширения у файла
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
                Console.WriteLine($"No match for file name and extension in URL {imageUri.AbsoluteUri}");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _httpClient.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Метод Main консольного приложения:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LoadImages().Wait();
        }

        static async Task LoadImages()
        {
            var imageLoader = new WebImageElementParser();
            var urls = await imageLoader.GetImageUrlsAsync("https://imgur.com/");
            using (var loader = new WebImageDownloader()) {
                foreach (var url in urls) {
                    await loader.SaveImageAsync(url);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

---