# Получить текст сылками на картинки в anglesharp

Tags: c#, html, .net, парсер

Допустим, имеется [страница](http://www.opengost.ru/iso/01_gosty/01040_gost_iso/0104017_gost_iso/1003-gost-24346-80-vibraciya.-terminy-i-opredeleniya.html), где в тексте есть картинки.

Например вот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно, если я выбираю все теги `<td>` и на них вызываю метод Text(), то ссылка теряется.

Есть ли простой способ получить текст и что бы на нужных местах были ссылки или мне нужно просматривать всех потомков `<td>` и самостоятельно формировать результрующую строку?

Comment: вам не <td> нужен, а вложенный в него (причем бывает, что не один) <img>.

Comment: Может оффтоп, но я просто [кардинально по другому парсю HTML](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/596145/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81/596355#596355). Имхо, намного проще выражать намерения через JavaScript, а не через код третьесторонней библиотеки.

Comment: @Bulson это да, но мне так же нужен и текст, который выше ссылки в блоке td. Получается нужно подучить все вложенные теги и руками создавать выходную строку?