# Получить изображение из reCAPTCHA

Tags: c#, .net, веб-программирование, recaptcha

Мне нужно пройти авторизацию на вебсайте средствами C#. В форме авторизации присутствует reCAPTCHA. Нужно как то её обработать (т.е. вытащить картинки, текст задания и позволить пользователю решить это дело).

Для начала, я вижу пустой `div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="..."`. Отсюда можно взять значение атрибута `data-sitekey`. Перейдём по ссылке `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=[data-sitekey value]` и загрузится примерно такая страничка:

```
var RecaptchaState = {
    challenge : '...',
    server : 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/',
    site : '...',
    ...
};

document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" s'+'rc="' + RecaptchaState.server + 'js/recaptcha.js"></scr'+'ipt>');
```

Каким образом я могу вытащить картинки с reCAPTCHA? Старая reCAPTCHA представлялась по видимому одной картинкой, которую можно было загрузить по такому адресу: `http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?c=[challenge from RecaptchaState]`. Что делать с новой, я не знаю. Не особо разбираюсь в веб-программировании.

---

**UPD:** Возможно есть иное решение, при котором нам не потребуется получать картинку. Может быть возможно как то отобразить капчу, чтобы её прошёл пользователь. Что то вроде WebBrowser, только не всю страницу, а лишь саму капчу, полученную из WebResponse.

Comment: Надо смотреть `recaptcha.js`, оно же все равно рисует картинку, посмотреть как и из чего, потом повторить :) сервисов рекапча куча же, как совет, поищете php реализацию для этого типа капчи, она наверняка есть в природе, и из php не составит труда понять что и как и повторить на C#.

Comment: Вот [тут](https://backender.ru/post/kak-ispolzovat-google-recaptcha-vmeste-s-php-i-javascript.html) и [тут](https://toster.ru/q/524908) и [тут](https://github.com/google/recaptcha/blob/1.0.0/php/recaptchalib.php) надеюсь это оно и вам это поможет :) ну и финальная [часть](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1203123/ReCaptcha-Solution-in-Csharp-No-External-JavaScrip)

Comment: Возможно ли просто отобразить это пользователю? Элемент из кода страницы. Что то наподобие WebBrowser, только с поддержкой js. Взаимодействие с сайтом осуществляется через WebRequest/WebRespose

Comment: Последняя ссылка [рабочий пример на C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1203123/ReCaptcha-Solution-in-Csharp-No-External-JavaScrip) , скачайте его :) и попробуйте.

Comment: Хорошо. Не поможете ещё с таким вопросом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/845766/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81-%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-data-reactid

Comment: Рекапча может давать вам не только одну картинку, а, например, задачу выбрать автомобиль или магазин по фото. И потом ещё раз и ещё раз. Другие компании, которые предлагают такие услуги, используют "хакнутый" браузер в котором можно подделывать адрес текущей страницы. Может быть вам проще *и дешевле* будет сразу к ним обратиться, чем изобретать свой велосипед.

Comment: @D.Stark Вот решение на основе браузерного контрола https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/596355/220571 Там не помешало бы использовать более свежий NuGet-пакет, а так там всё ок.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov CefSharp мне подходит. Только загрузить то он всю страничку с формой авторизации, а мне нужна только recaptcha. Т.е. нужно изменить код страницы таким образом, чтобы видна была только капча. Может быть выполнить скрипт, который скроет все элементы на странице кроме нужного?

Comment: @D.Stark Конечно, почему бы и нет? Вы же можете выполнять во встронном браузере произвольный JavaScript.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Это понятно. Я подумал вдруг у CEF есть какие то доп. возможности, которые упростят задачу ещё. Наверно вы не знаете..

Comment: @D.Stark Так по-моему это так просто делается с помощью JavaScript…

Answer (score 1):

Я открываю сайт в WebBrowser, получаю все картинки с сайта и так нахожу саму картинку капчи:

```
private void openAndWaitCompliteURL(string url) {
            webBrowser.Navigate(url);
            while (webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
        }
private string getImageWhenLoad(string attr) {
        HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser.Document;
        HtmlElementCollection htmlElementCollection = doc.Images;
        foreach (HtmlElement htmlElement in htmlElementCollection) {
            string imgUrl = htmlElement.GetAttribute(attr);
            return imgUrl;
        }
    }
openAndWaitCompliteURL(url);
capchaForm.capchaPictureBox.ImageLocation = getImageWhenLoad("src");
```

После чего вывожу картинку в PictureBox.

Comment: Я не использую WebBrowser, т.к. нужный мне сайт он грузит некорректно. И вообще поддержка JS там хреновая. Надо решение на CefSharp. Вы могли бы помочь только тем, если бы предложили скрипт, который скроет все элементы визуального дерева кроме `<div class="g-recaptcha" ..`

Comment: @D.Stark Но в вопросе нет ничего про CefSharp и скрытие визуального дерева... Да и зачем мучиться со скрытием отдельных элементов, проще скрыть весь браузер и картинку показать отдельно (если там действительно картинка).

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Прочтите комментарии к вопросу. Картинка может быть не одна, при этом изображения могут подгружаться по мере решения. И, а что если я не правильно решу?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight "Но в вопросе нет ничего про CefSharp и скрытие визуального дерева" - в комментариях есть

Comment: Задайте отдельный вопрос про элементы визуального дерева

Comment: @Виталий, а как у вас находиться нужная 'картинка' в представленном коде, просто интересно.. там вероятно не одна картинка в этом урл.. и for each просто возвращает первую, то есть он там просто лишний, или я не прав?