# Нажать на кнопку с атрибутом data-reactid

Tags: c#, .net, веб-программирование

На сайте имеются элементы с атрибутом data-reactid. В них, так понимаю, данные подгружаются динамически. Работаю через WebRequest/WebResponse. Не особо понимаю как взаимодействовать с такими элементами. Например, как можно нажать на кнопку с атрибутом data-reactid?

Comment: Атрибут роли не играет при нажимании (событие Click) в жсскрипт. Он сам разбегаться что с ним делать, вам главное его программно нажать :)

Comment: А как правильно нажимать? Я не использую здесь WebBrowser.

Comment: Или считать данные с input например

Comment: Парсить статистическую страницу? толком ничего не выйдет, надо создавать объект типа WebBrowser или Chrom воткнуть, и выполнять в нем, фактически, можно выполнять только Ява скрипт интерпретатором, но надо выполняемый скрипт во что то обернуться, чтоб он писал в переменные, а не в инпуты и дивы HTML.

Comment: И во что его можно обернуть? У WebBrowser вроде как есть аналоги, которые позволяют выполнять JS. Что посоветуете? CefSharp?

Comment: Да что работает, то и берите, Cef это Хром, он естественно модный, но, и дефоултный контрол с ИЕ вполне подойдёт на мой взгляд. Что удобнее и понятнее то и берите, чтоб не захломлять, лучше сначала пробывать дефаултный контрол.

Comment: А скрипт то во что обернуть?

Comment: В другой скрипт :) где переопределить вывод, или переписать авторский код, что проще по сути.. Надо подойти изначально с точки зрения Ява интерпретатором, и посмотреть его (выбранного) возможности и методы, если ИЕ то одни, у Хрома побольше возможностей, можно взять дефолтный из студии.. вариантов то много, надо остановиться сперва на инструменте, от этого зависит конкретные шаги по решению. Для [общего ознакомления](https://habr.com/post/115021/)

Comment: Ага. Т.е. вы предлагаете загрузить скрипт, запустить его в Java интерпретаторе, переопределить вывод на переменные и всё готово? А как понять какой именно скрипт нам нужен? Который выполниться при нажатии на кнопку. Посмотреть каким то расширением для браузера?

Comment: Правильно, именно такой путь, в вашем случае проще начать с webBrowser контрола, разберетесь, можно будет портировать под  иной интерпретатор. Ссылки можно посмотреть во время обмена, в том же контроле, какой адрес итд. или плагины для ОгненнойЛисы :)

Comment: Я попробовал просто загрузить сайт методом `WebBrowser.Navigate`. Загрузилось криво косо и с кучей ошибок выполнения скриптов.

Comment: СefSharp справился получше. Всё работает, но выглядит не как в оригинале. Наверно какие нибудь стили не "прогрузились". Мне это не важно.

Comment: Может быть нажать кнопку будет проще используя метод `webBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync`? Запустить скрипт который сможет по XPath (у неё нет id) найти кнопку и её нажать. Это возможно?

Comment: Ну как бы всё равно нужно будет писать обёртку (в виде так понял другого скрипта, который будем выполнять через `ExecuteScript`) над выполняемым скриптом, чтобы он обновлял некоторые нужные мне данные не в коде странички, а в переменных. Это да. Но вопрос как понять какой именно скрипт из чуть более чем десятка занимается обновлением данных. Как это сделать используя проект CefSharp?

Comment: @NewView Скрипт нашёл через chrome dev tools. Он обновляет все данные на страничке. Только нужную мне информацию не то что пишет, а рисует в canvas. Как скриптом направить вывод на мои переменные в С#?

Comment: @NewView https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/847641/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-js-%D1%81-html-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-c

Comment: @NewView Я так и не понял что вы имели ввиду на счёт скрипта-обёртки... Как это так можно обернуть один скрипт в другой? Там используется ReactJS и данные хранятся в компоненте Chart. Я не хочу изменять авторский скрипт.