# Перенаправить вывод JS с HTML на переменные C#

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, reactjs, cefsharp

Использую CefSharp.WPF

Задача состоит в получении текущего значения динамически изменяемого графика.
Отыскав ответственный за обновление данных скрипт, нашёл вот такой пример:

```
define('components/Chart', ['lib/react'], function (React) {
    return React.createClass({
        displayName: 'Chart',
        ...
        _draw: function () {
            var canvas = this.refs.canvas.getDOMNode();
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            this.graph.setData(...);
            this.graph.calculatePlotValues();
            this.graph.clean();
            this.graph.drawAxes();
            this.graph.drawGraph();
            this.graph.drawIndexes();
            this.graph.drawData(...);
        }
        ...
        render: function () {
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

*`this.graph` - имеет тип `Graph` и определён аналогичным образом (через `define` и `React.createClass`).

Сайт рисует график на canvas с о чём то говорящим атрибутом `data-reactid`.

Я в JS не разбираюсь, но задача была поставлена так, что об этом сожалею :)
Однако, прошу помочь мне разобраться что, собственно, этот скрипт делает. Думаю представленного общего вида хватит, чтобы это понять.

Разобравшись с этим, я планирую как то переопределить, если это возможно, Chart, чтобы тот не рисовал данные на canvas, а писал их в глобальную переменную, откуда я мог бы методом `EvaluateScriptAsync` это читать.

---

Было предложение создать аналогичный класс в C#, затем зарегистрировать его в JS методом `RegisterJsObject`. Таким образом, мы получим контроль над данными внутри класса, что нам и нужно. Однако, остаётся вопросом как правильно это сделать и будет ли это работать...

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79615/discussion-on-question-by-d-stark---js--html---c).

Answer (score 0):

`React` это библиотека для отрисовки пользовательских компонентов, нынче очень популярна за счет своей архитектуры и философии. [Тут](https://reactjs.org) можно посмотреть что да как.

Если вкратце, то в `React` любой элемент интерфейса - это компонент, у которого есть состояние `state` и который может принимать св-ва `props`, за счет них компонент возвращает вполне реальный `DOM`.

Каждый компонент описывается классом, которые наследуется от базового `React.Component`. Метод `render` как раз таки возвращает `DOM` ( на самом деле все чуть сложнее, но к делу не относится )

Простой пример:

```
class SimpleComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>Hello, world</div>
        );
    }
}
```

`data-reactid` это просто атрибут показывающий корневой элемент, где находится все приложение.

В зависимости от версии, которую вы используете ( судя по `createClass` оч старая ) можно попробовать вытащить данные из `DOM`. Но надо знать точную версию, без нее помочь вам с этим не смогу.

Ели все таки хотите менять код, то переопределите метод `createClass`: добавляйте все инстансы в какой-нибудь массив/объект, что бы потом по ссылке получать актуальный компонент

Вот конструктор, который возвращает `createClass`, можно в нем поменять кое-что ( брал код от [сюда](https://unpkg.com/react@0.13.0-rc1/dist/react.js) )

```
createClass: function(spec) {
  var Constructor = function(props, context) {
    // код библиотеки

    // добавляем экземпляр в глобальный массив
    if(!window.globalComponents) {
      window.globalComponents = [];
    }
    window.globalComponents.push(this);
  }
  // остальной код
};
```

Потом можно легко по `displayName` найти наш компонент

```
window.globalComponents.find(c => c.displayName === 'Chart');
```

Comment: "_Если все таки хотите менять код, то переопределите метод createClass"_ - Менять код не желательно наверное и не обязательно. "_Но надо знать точную версию, без нее помочь вам с этим не смогу"_ - Версию ReactJS? Как узнать, где посмотреть?

Comment: @D.Stark, в файле, который подключается можно версию глянуть

Comment: React (with addons) v0.12.1

Comment: "_В зависимости от версии, которую вы используете ( судя по createClass оч старая ) можно попробовать вытащить данные из DOM. Но надо знать точную версию, без нее помочь вам с этим не смогу._" - Как это сделать? Добавите, пожалуйста, в ответ разъяснения для указанной мною версии ReactJS