# Html Agility Pack не может спарсить сайт

Tags: c#, парсер, htmlagilitypack

При попытке выполнить

```
var htmlDoc = web.Load("https://vprognoze.ru/");
```

получаю такой вот код страницы. При чем этот код приходит от парсинга любой страницы сайта. Что это за защита и как её обойти?

[image: Скрин]

Comment: Похоже, содержимое сайта подтягивается динамически на js. Вам нужен способ, позволяющий исполнять javascript. Например, можно использовать CEF: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/596363/184217), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/596355/184217). Или компонент `WebBrowser`.

Comment: Действительно, всё свелось к проблеме наличия iframes в коде, с чем HAP  справиться не может, по крайней мере без применения компонента-костыля webBrowser. Парсинг успешно прошел, спасибо!